# SimpleSchema invalid keys "_id required"

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I'm using aldeed:autoform, aldeed:simple-schema, aldeed:collection2 and mdg:validated-method for doing an insert over a collection.

This is the tempalte with the AutoForm:

```
<template name="Areas_agregar">
  {{> Titulos_modulos title="Areas" subtitle="Agregar" cerrar=true}} 
  {{ 
    #autoForm 
    collection=areasColecction 
    id="areas_agregar" 
    type="method" 
    meteormethod="areas.insert" 
  }} 
  {{> afQuickField name='nombre'}} 
  {{> afArrayField name='subareas'}}

  <button type="submit">Save</button>

  <button type="reset">Reset Form</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

This is the collection's schema:

```
Areas.schema = new SimpleSchema({
    _id: { 
        type: String, 
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id 
    },
    nombre: { 
        type: String,
        label: 'Nombre'
    },
    subareas: {
        type: [String],
        label: 'Subareas'
    }
});
```

And this is the insert method:

```
const AREA_FIELDS_ONLY = Areas.simpleSchema().pick(['nombre', 'subareas', 'subareas.$']).validator({ clean: true, filter: false });

export const insert = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: 'areas.insert',
    validate: AREA_FIELDS_ONLY,
    run({ nombre, subareas }) {
        const area = {
            nombre, 
            subareas
        };
        Areas.insert(area);
    },
});
```

And i'm getting the folowing error in Chrome's Dev Console:

SimpleSchema invalid keys for "areas_agregar" context: 
Array[1]
    0: Object
        **name: "_id"
        type: "required"**
        value: null
        **proto**: Object
        length: 1
        **proto**: Array[0]

Like the error shows, is asking me a value for the _id field, but I'm on an insert update, it doesn't makes any sense.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: If you make the `_id` `optional: true` then your insert will work and Meteor will automatically insert the `_id`

Comment: Yes! That worked. But why in the 'todos' example project, there's no `_id optional: true` in the `_id` field?

Comment: Does that project use autoform?

Comment: No, it does not, but it uses simple-schema and validated-method

Comment: Right - but I think that when you use the same schema for autoform it treats required keys as being required in the form input itself, not just post-insertion.

Comment: It seems that that's the problem. I think I'll open an issue in AutoForm's GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autoform treats required keys in the schema as being required in the form input which doesn't work for the `_id` key.

If you make the _id optional: true then your insert will work and Meteor will automatically insert the `_id` OR you can use a variation of the schema for the autoform which omits the `_id` key altogether:

```
let schemaObject = {
  nombre: { 
    type: String,
    label: 'Nombre'
  },
  subareas: {
    type: [String],
    label: 'Subareas'
  }
};
Areas.formSchema = new SimpleSchema(schemaObject); // use for form
schemaObject._id = { 
  type: String, 
  regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id 
};
Areas.collectionSchema = new SimpleSchema(schemaObject); // use for collection
```

Comment: Thanks Michel. That's a pretty elegant solution.